# ML.NET training with floats arrays

Tags: ml.net

I fail to understand the transform component. Basically I have generated 1 million training samples

```
public class Data{

public float[] Input;

public float[] Output;

}
```

I want to train a net with 100 layers and then check the output prediction. Input is 1000 in size, and output is 500 in size

The library continue to throw "schema mismatch for feature column"

Comment: That error often indicates a discrepancy between the data schema expected by transform component and the actual data provided. Like this `[VectorType(1000)] public float[] Input` and `[VectorType(500)] public float[] Output`

Comment: Want me post my above comment as an answer? if it solved your problem

Comment: Yes it solved but found another problema in working with ML.NET and arrays of floats, so finally I switched to NeuralNetwork.NET which has none of this problems

Comment: For another problem, it's better post a new question, so we will be there.

Answer (score 0):

That error often indicates a **discrepancy** between the data schema expected by transform component and the actual data provided.

Like this:

```
[VectorType(1000)] public float[] Input
```

And:

```
[VectorType(500)] public float[] Output
```